# jQuery create function and call it on each separately

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey guys I'm trying to create a function and call it inside another each loop.  I got it to work, but the each loop is not working.  So I tried to add an extra `$(this)` and it didn't work either...any help is appreciated.

```
.moveClass {
position:relative;
}

$(function() {

$('.a_projectLoad').each(function(evt){
    $(this).hover(function(){
        $(this).slideRight();
    });
});

});

function slideRight () {
    $('.img_rightArrow')
        .addClass('moveClass')
        .animate({"left": "+=50px"}, "fast");
}

<table>
             <tr>
                <td><a href="#" class="a_projectLoad">Title Goes Here</a></td>
                <td ><img src="images/btn_loadProject.png" class="img_rightArrow"/></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><a href="#" class="a_projectLoad">Title Goes Here</a></td>
                <td><img src="images/btn_loadProject.png" class="img_rightArrow"/></td>
              </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `position: relative` attribute to your images directly as part of the markup rather than programmatically via JavaScript. This will not alter its initial rendering and therefore should not be done in code.

Next, bind a custom slideRight event and invoke it on hover as follows:

```
$(function() {

    // Bind a custom slideRight event to each image
    $('img.img_rightArrow').bind({
        slideRight: function () {
            $(this).stop(true, true).animate({"left": "+=50px"}, "fast");
        },
        slideLeft: function () {
            $(this).stop(true, true).animate({"left": "-=50px"}, "fast");
        }
    });

    $('a.a_projectLoad').hover(function () {
        // Traverse DOM to find nearby arrow image
        $(this).closest("tr").find("img.img_rightArrow").trigger("slideRight");
    }, function () {
        $(this).closest("tr").find("img.img_rightArrow").trigger("slideLeft");
    });

});
```

FYI: your images are missing the `img_rightArrow` class in the sample markup.

You could probably use a second functional parameter to [.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) to bind to the mouseout event. Check out [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) for more information. I assume in your example it might be something of the sort of a trigger to a slideLeft event. Just a thought however.

Comment: Thanks! works great...now I'm just wondering when if at all you would ever use `$('.a_projectLoad').each(function(evt){
  $(this).hover(function(){
   callback: slideRight;
  });
 });`

Comment: @webwrks You should check out the documentation for [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) as I don't think you quite got the gist of what it does. Given a set of elements from a selector, it passes two parameters to the function you provide it: the index of the element, and the element itself (which is also available within the function's context as "this"). You would normally use it to pass each element off to a function that performs a behavior not already shorthanded by jQuery.

Comment: #lthibodwaux...`$(function() {
    $('img.img_rightArrow').bind("slideRight", function () {
        $(this).addClass('moveClass').animate({"left": "+=50px"}, "fast");
    });
 
 $('img.img_rightArrow').bind("slideLeft", function () {
        $(this).addClass('moveClass').animate({"left": "-=50px"}, "fast");
    });

    $('a.a_projectLoad').hover(function () {
        $(this).closest("tr").find("img.img_rightArrow").trigger("slideRight");
    }, function () {
        $(this).closest("tr").find("img.img_rightArrow").trigger("slideLeft")
    });

});` works great but it fires animations, one()?

Comment: @webwrks I'm sorry, but could you restate the question? And to bind a second event, just use the return from the first bind so you don't reselect everything. jQuery works by using functional call chaining and always returning the jQuery object at the end of each call, i.e.: `$('img.img_rightArrow').bind("slideRight", function () {}).bind("slideLeft", function() {})`. You can also pass in a mapping object to .bind(), i.e.: `$('img.img_rightArrow').bind({slideRight: function () {}, slideLeft: function() {}})`  I'll add some edits to demonstrate.

Comment: I trying to place the `.stop()` correctly to prevent buildup.  Thanks for the great advice!

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this ?

```
$('.a_projectLoad').each(function(evt){
        $(this).hover(slideRight);
    });

function slideRight () {

    $('.img_rightArrow')
        .addClass('moveClass')
        .animate({"left": "+=50px"}, "fast");
}


});
```

It works me